# bluetoothctl scans stop working after some hours

Tags: linux, bluetooth, expect

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866209/qt5-bluetooth-scanning-at-regular-intervals-freezes-the-program), I have tried to check if the bug I found with QtBluetooth was connected to bluetoothctl. To do this, I have run this shell script (using [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)) in a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set prompt "#"

spawn /usr/bin/bluetoothctl
expect $prompt
send "scan on\r\n"
sleep 10
send "scan off\r\n"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
```

The end goal is to continuously log all the devices around the sensor for an unspecified amount of time (to put a reasonable estimate, consider at least 24 hours of continous operation, with a bluetooth scan performed every 10 seconds).

After around three hours of successful scans, bluetoothctl showed the same behavior as in the linked question (the scan starts, ends, finds no devices despite them being present and discoverable).

Is there anything preventing bluetoothctl to work for this specific task by design? If not, is there any workaround for solving this issue? I'm running the above code on a Linux machine, with **Ubuntu 18.10** installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this as an answer for those who might stumble on the same problem and (incorrectly) thinking it to be a programming issue.

This problem is not directly connected with either `expect` or `bluetoothctl`. By browsing the event log (**dmesg --ctime**), I found out that, every time this behavior manifested, this line popped out: `Bluetooth: hci0: command <number> tx timeout`, with different command numbers. By googling this specific error, it turned out that it might related to the Linux kernel itself, the drivers of the bluetooth device or the power saving options of my Linux machine.